# How to extend some style object in react native

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

I want to make an `base style` and extend others by base.How to implement it in react native code.

```
tvSmallDefault : {fontSize : Dimens.tvDefaultSmall, color : Colors.black},
tvNormalDefault : {fontSize : Dimens.tvDefaultNormal, color : Colors.black},
```

Here i gave black color in both above styles. How to make an base style and use it in both, something like this.

```
base: {color : Colors.black},
tvSmallDefault parent base: {fontSize : Dimens.tvDefaultSmall},
tvNormalDefault parent base : {fontSize : Dimens.tvDefaultNormal},
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could declare the base style as an object, then mix it in using the `...` spread operator (or `Object.assign` if the spread operator isn't available)

```
const baseStyle = { color: Colors.black }

const tvSmallDefault = { ...baseStyle, fontSize: Dimens.tvDefaultSmall }
const tvNormalDefault = { ...baseStyle, fontSize: Dimens.tvDefaultNormal }
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Comment: And wrap it with `StyleSheet.create` , right? Like `StyleSheet.create(tvNormalDefault)`

Comment: Well, you'd assign them as properties in the object passed to StyleSheet.create, like `StyleSheet.create({ tvNormalDefault, tvSmallDefault })`. I only declared them here as variables for sake of example

Comment: Right @kingdaro, I also dont use StyleSheet.cretae

Comment: export default {
  tvDefault: { color: Colors.textPrimary },
  tvSmallDefault: { ...tvDefault, fontSize: Dimens.tvDefaultSmall }}

Comment: I tried to do something like this. but not working, It says cant find variable tvDefault

Comment: You have to declare the `tvDefault` as a variable separately outside of the object

Comment: Is there not any solution because i have created long styles class as above. Also let me know if i am following wrong way to make styles.

Comment: const tvDefault = { color: Colors.textPrimary },

export default {

  tvSmallDefault: { ...tvDefault, fontSize: Dimens.tvDefaultSmall }}

Comment: This does not work too. It gives error "unexpected token" for line tvDefault.

Comment: Because the `const tvDefault = ...` line ends in a comma when it should be a semicolon (or new line)

Comment: Also, if you have other problems, best ask a new question instead of continuing it in comments, or move to chat.

Comment: Thanks dude, yes it was syntax issue. ;) i am very fresher to react.